# I am getting array of objects but I need objects in a single array by mongodb query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi I am new to mongodb trying to achieve a output using mongodb aggregate I am trying to achieve a single array of objects instead of multiple array of objects can anyone help me to achieve my desired output

Below I have mentioned my model and I have mentioned my query, I am getting array of objects but I need a combined single array of objects I need to achieve it by mongodb query.

This is my mongodb model

```
db={
  "teacher": [
    {
      "rating": 4,
      "teacher_id": "123",
      "course_count": 1,
      
    },
    {
      "rating": 5,
      "teacher_id": "456",
      "course_count": 4,
      
    },
    {
      "rating": 5,
      "teacher_id": "no-exists",
      "course_count": 4,
      
    }
  ],
  "course": [
    {
      "teacher_id": "123",
      "cid": "1",
      "advanced": true,
      
    },
    {
      "teacher_id": "456",
      "cid": "1",
      "advanced": true,
      
    }
  ]
}
```

this is my mongodb query

```
db.course.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "cid": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "localField": "teacher_id",
      "from": "teacher",
      "foreignField": "teacher_id",
      "as": "teacher"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$teacher",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      cid: 1,
      teacher: 1
    }
  },
  
])
```

I am getting this output

```
[
  {
    "cid": "1",
    "teacher": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
      "course_count": 1,
      "rating": 4,
      "teacher_id": "123"
    }
  },
  {
    "cid": "1",
    "teacher": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
      "course_count": 4,
      "rating": 5,
      "teacher_id": "456"
    }
  }
]
```

this is my desired output

```
  {
    "cid": "1",
    "advance":true
    "teacher": [{
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
      "course_count": 1,
      "rating": 4,
      "teacher_id": "123"
    },
   {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
      "course_count": 4,
      "rating": 5,
      "teacher_id": "456"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Please take this with some caution, as I have not used MongoDB before, so what I suggest might not be possible (I'm coming from a RDBMS background). Can you group the `teacher`s by the `cid` key, and then inside that grouping, group again, this time by the `teacher` key? That way, you'd end up with `{"cid": "1","teacher" : [ ...]}`.

Comment: Thanks for reference, but I'm unable to achieve desired output by grouping them.

Comment: One last try, then, and then I'll give up. :) Grouping seems to be the key, combined with [`$push`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#mongodb-group-grp.-push). Please take a look at the following, and let me know if it works for you: https://mongoplayground.net/p/oACyo7-JpbN

Answer (score 1):

You need to group  the documents by using  `cid` field and then push `teacher` document into array.

```js
db.course.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      cid: "1"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      localField: "teacher_id",
      from: "teacher",
      foreignField: "teacher_id",
      as: "teacher"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$teacher",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$cid",
      advanced: {
        $first: "$advanced"
      },
      teacher: {
        $push: "$teacher"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      cid: "$_id",
      advanced: 1,
      teacher: 1
    }
  }
])
```

If you have any issue,you can ask